# Configuring a Node project with sub modules in CircleCI

Tags: unit-testing, npm, automated-tests, circleci

We have a project in Git containing several modules with the following structures:

```
project
|- module1
  |- package.json
  (...)
|- module2
  |- package.json
  (...)
```

Each `package.json` file has a `test` entry to execute tests of the module. So we can execute tests for a particular module like this (in the corresponding sub folder):

```
$ npm run test
```

Is it possible to configure such a project in CircleCI?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, in a very similar fashion to how you would do it locally. In your `circle.yml` file test section, you would have a line for each module. Something like:

```
test:
  override:
    - cd module1; npm run test
    - cd module2; npm run test
```

More information on how to use `circle.yml` can be found [here](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#test).

-Ricardo
Developer Evangelist, CircleCI

Comment: This does not seem to work in my case. How can you use pwd property?

Comment: I suggest writing a new post at https://discuss.circleci.com to get help with your issue. Or at the very least, a new Stack Overflow question.